# Zend Framework: Central point to implement code to be run in every controller+action

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

What would be the best place to implement some code that would be run before every action in every controller in every module of my app ?

`_init*` method in `Bootstrap.php`  ?

`index.php` is not an option because in need to access code that is prepared in `bootstrap.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html

> The controller architecture includes a plugin system that allows user code to be called when certain events occur in the controller process lifetime. The front controller uses a plugin broker as a registry for user plugins, and the plugin broker ensures that event methods are called on each plugin registered with the front controller.

You are likely looking to hook into:

> `preDispatch()` is called before an action is dispatched by the dispatcher. This callback allows for proxy or filter behavior.